# How do I add a slash command for certain users to use?

Tags: discord.js

How do I make a slash command for a specific user that has the role "Moderator"? When other users try to use it it will be disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add permissions to a certain slash command by using the `command.permissions.add()` function. Your code will look like this:

```js
const command = client.application?.commands.fetch('YOUR_COMMAND_ID');

const permissions = [{
    id: 'ROLE_ID',
    type: 'ROLE',
    permission: true,
}];

await command.permissions.add({permissions});
```

Source: https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-command-permissions.html#role-permissions

### Edit:

As mentioned by @SollyBunny in the comments, the page has been removed. Here is another source: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/ApplicationCommandPermissionsManager

Comment: *this comment must be 15 character in length*: dead link