# Only let users with a specific permission use kick slash command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I know how to make it so that only ME can use a slash command, that way if someone isn't me and tries to use my slash command it will be gray like :

[image: grey slash command]

```js
client.application.commands.permissions.set([
  {
    id : cmd.id,
    permissions : [
      {
        type : 'USER',
        id : 'My id',
        permission : true
      }
    ]
  }
])
```

How to do the same thing for permissions ? How to do it so that only members with a specific role can use the command ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a slash command for certain users to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69512068/how-do-i-add-a-slash-command-for-certain-users-to-use)

Comment: @jefffishandsome No, I know to set permissions to users but i'm asking for limit them for permissions, like BAN_MEMBERS etc..

Comment: @MalikLahlou I don't think that is possible at the moment. Your best solution is to create roles called `BAN_MEMBERS`, for example, and set the permissions for that role.

Comment: By the way, I think you can only have up to 10 permission per user.